# Covariance and Contravariance related understanding the point and architecture

Tags: c#

First of all apologize for long post nevertheless i wanted to highlight problem exactly and to be most readable and understandably. I am developing architecture of my program which will be responsible for files/databases data gather and face some architecture issues so far. All information step by step down below.

Let's consider following code below:

```
public interface IWatchService<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    IList<TEntity> MatchingEntries { get; set; }
}

public interface IWatchServiceDatabase<TEntity> : IWatchService<TEntity> where TEntity : IDatabaseEntity
{ }
public interface IWatchServiceFiles<TEntity> : IWatchService<TEntity> where TEntity : IFileEntity
{ }

class Database : IWatchServiceDatabase<DatabaseQuery>
{
    public IList<DatabaseQuery> MatchingEntries { get; set; }
}

class Files : IWatchServiceFiles<CsvFile>
{
    public IList<CsvFile> MatchingEntries { get; set; }
}

class Consumer
{
    public IWatchService<IEntity> WatchService { get; set; }

    public Consumer(IWatchService<IEntity> watchService)
    {
        WatchService = watchService;
        var newList = WatchService.MatchingEntries;
    }


   public void AddNewEntries(IEntity entity) => WatchService.MatchingEntries.Add(entity);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWatchServiceDatabase<DatabaseQuery> db = new Database();
        IWatchServiceFiles<CsvFile> filesCsv = new Files();

        var dbConsumer = new Consumer(db);                  //cannot convert from 'IWatchServiceDatabase<DatabaseQuery>' to 'IWatchService<IEntity>' 
        var filesCsvConsumer = new Consumer(filesCsv);            //cannot convert from 'IWatchServiceFiles<CsvFile>'          to 'IWatchService<IEntity>'

        dbConsumer.AddNewEntries(new DatabaseQuery());
        dbConsumer.AddNewEntries(new CsvFile());            //illegal cause it's not FileConsumer !!!

        filesCsvConsumer.AddNewEntries(new CsvFile());
        filesCsvConsumer.AddNewEntries(new DatabaseQuery());   //illegal cause it's not DbConsumer !!!
     }
}

public interface IEntity { }

public interface IFileEntity : IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IDatabaseEntity : IEntity { }

public class CsvFile : IFileEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class XmlFile : IFileEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseQuery : IDatabaseEntity { }
```

We have two errors there:

```
var dbConsumer = new Consumer(db);      
var filesCsvConsumer = new Consumer(filesCsv);
```

Errors:

> cannot convert from 'IWatchServiceDatabase' to 'IWatchService'
>   cannot convert from 'IWatchServiceFiles' to 'IWatchService'

This seems to be understandable because otherwise "we would be able" to add `CsvFile` or `XmlFile` to `dbConsumer` where generic `IDatabaseEntity` is expected and `CsvFile` and `XmlFile` are in fact `IFileEntity` and from the other hand `DatabaseQuery` to `filesConsumer` which expects `IFileEntity` and `DatabaseQuery` is `IDatabaseEntity`

```
//Database related
dbConsumer.AddNewEntries(new DatabaseQuery());
dbConsumer.AddNewEntries(new CsvFile());    //illegal cause it's not FileConsumer !!!

//Files related
filesCsvConsumer.AddNewEntries(new CsvFile());  
filesCsvConsumer.AddNewEntries(new DatabaseQuery());  //illegal cause it's not DbConsumer !!!
```

From my understanding this is the clue why compiler raise those errors and which is fine. Therefore I've decided to overcome it in this way:

```
public interface IWatchService<out TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
     IEnumerable<TEntity> MatchingEntries { get; }
}
```

As can be seen i marked generic parameter out and changed `IList to IEnumerable` because `IEnumerable` can be only `foreached`. Without possibility to modify the list.

Now having this there is no possibility to modify `MatchingEntries` e.g `Add()` on therefore we are now not able to add e.g `CsvFile (IFileEntity)` where `IDatabaseEntity` is expected and vice versa `DatabaseQuery (IDatabaseEntity)` where `IFileEntity` is expected. Fine and understandably.

At the end i have two main questions:

What is the benefit to have this: `IEnumerable MatchingEntries { get; }` since it's `{get;}` it cannot be initialized or populated with values therefore i would always get empty list when calling that property. Or i am in wrong? Can somebody explain showing based on my code what can be done with it?

Let's imagine i want to have possibility to `Add items` to this `MatchingEntries` list and in `Consumer` class i want still to be able to pass in `ctor` either `Database` or `Files` related classes based on interfaces. How this can be accomplished? Please also show an example based on current code.

Many thanks for your support and hope someone benefit from it as i saw a lot of confusions related to that topic.

Comment: We require that the code be posted by an author or maintainer of the code, that the code be embedded directly, and that the poster know why the code is written the way it is. Please [follow the tour](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Henry: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BLhIPF provides an example of a simple class with both a consumer interface and a producer interface.  Note that the only benefit of this division is that the consumer interface can be more general (if necessary) and the producer interface can be more specific (if necessary).  When accessing the class directly, you can already be more general when consuming and more specific when producing.  So, this interface split is not necessarily useful.

Answer (score 3):

First question:

> What is the benefit to have this: `IEnumerable<T> MatchingEntries { get; }` since it's `{get;}` it cannot be initialized or populated with values therefore I would always get empty list when calling that property. Or I am in wrong? Can somebody explain showing based on my code what can be done with it?

I am confused by the question. The interface says that a class that implements that interface must have a getter of this name and type. It says nothing at all about the contents of that sequence:

```
interface IFoo<out T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Bar { get; }
}
```

Now we can implement that interface however we want:

```
class TigerFoo : IFoo<Tiger>
{
    public IEnumerable<Tiger> Bar 
    {
        get 
        {
            return new List<Tiger>() { new Tiger("Tony"), new Tiger("Terry") };
        }
    }
}
```

So why you think the returned sequence must be empty, I do not understand.

Similarly, nothing is stopping you from making a class that implements a setter:

```
class GiraffeFoo : IFoo<Giraffe>
{
    public IEnumerable<Giraffe> Bar { get; set; } 
}
…
GiraffeFoo gf = new GiraffeFoo();
List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe>() { new Giraffe("Gerry") };
gf.Bar = giraffes;
```

Nothing stops you from changing the contents of the list:

```
class TurtleFoo : IFoo<Turtle>
{
    private List<Turtle> turtles = new List<Turtle>();
    public IEnumerable<Turtle> Bar => turtles;
    public void AddATurtle() => turtles.Add(new Turtle("Tommy"));
}
```

It is a mystery to me why you think you cannot do any of these things. You want to add a member to the collection? **Write a method that adds a member to the collection**.  You just can't put it in the *interface* if you wan the interface to be covariant. But the interface tells you what services you *must* provide, not what services you must *not* provide! I do not understand why you think that an interface tells you what a class *cannot* do.

Since `T` is marked as `out`, you can now use any of these covariantly:

```
IFoo<Animal> ia1 = new TigerFoo();
IFoo<Animal> ia2 = new GiraffeFoo();
IFoo<Animal> ia3 = new TurtleFoo();
```

Of course you don't get to use the methods of the class once it is in an interface, but you never get to use the methods of a class once something is in an interface.

Second question:

> Let's imagine I want to have possibility to Add items to this MatchingEntries list and in Consumer class i want still to be able to pass in ctor either Database or Files related classes based on interfaces. How this can be accomplished? Please also show an example based on current code.

Just write code that does that. I don't understand what the question is asking. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I understood your post but i have problems to reflect that in my code. First of all my consumer class have to take in ctor both database and files class what option do i have? Only iwatchservice<ientity> and in this case it will not work as i wrote becuase of errors. How you woukd accomplish that? Second case.about this add .. i already tried to do in consumer class inn my AddNewEntries method. However this is not working due to bad.convertion. how you would accomplish both problems?